# Connected ball $B(x,r)$ in an arbitrary space $\Omega$

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

Are balls always connected? Or is there a condition on a ball $B(x,r)$ to be connected? Where $x$ is an arbitrary point in an arbitrary space $\Omega$, and $r>0$

Comment: An easy counterexample is a plane with a segment removed. Consider a small ball around a point near the middle of the segment (it gets split in twain).

Answer (score 0):

All balls in $\Bbb Q$ (usual metric) are disconnected. In a real linear space with a norm-induced metric all balls will be convex and so path-connected. This includes spaces like $\Bbb R^n$ etc.